# CSS grid with floats, not working if the class that set the widths is not first

Tags: css

For a grid I have the code bellow.

As, you can see for `Example 2` the code:

```
[class^="col-"] {
    float: left;
}
```

doesn't work, created the grid.

I want to know if there is an option, to use something similar, that works indifferent of the class `col-`position. I know I can add a separate class 'col' for floats in html, but I prefer not to do it.

```css
.red, .blue {
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
}

.red {
background-color: red;
}

.blue {
background-color: blue;

}

.row{ 
  width: 2200px;
  overflow: auto;
 }
 
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

[class^="col-"] {
    float: left;
}

.col-3 {
    width: 30%;
}


.col--7 {
    width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <h1> Example 1</h1> 
  <div class="col-3 red">lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="col-7 blue">ipsum ipsum</div>
</div>  

<div class="row">
  <h1> Example 2</h1> 
  <div class="red col-3">lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="blue col-7">ipsum ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.red, .blue {
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

[class*="col-"] {
  float: left;
}

.col-3 {
  width: 30%;
}

.col-7 {
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <h1> Example 1</h1>
  <div class="col-3 red">lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="col-7 blue">ipsum ipsum</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <h1> Example 2</h1>
  <div class="red col-3">lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="blue col-7">ipsum ipsum</div>
</div>
```